# How to use Angular routing?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have a page(say page3) which can be accessed from two other pages say page1(parent URL will be parent1 - parent1/page1) and page 2(parent URL will be parent2 - parent2/page2).

Since angular changes the URL by default i want to prevent that URL change only if i am navigating from page2 and i want the URL to change normally when i am navigating from page 1(for all pages with parent url as parent1).

We can do this by

```
router.navigate('page2',{skipLocationChange: true});
```

but how can I do this in a common place since I have more pages like page4, page5, page6, etc and I want to prevent location change only for particular pages.

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to router events in specific components:
https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationStart-class.html

In the event handler (after navigation kicks in) you can check what is the parent URL and override it with methods such as `history.replaceState()`

You could crate global configuration injectable that will have have all rules defined (i.e. which URL to override and which do not). This way you won't need to refactor all `router.navigate` but only specify the rule once per component in the component class:

```
constructor(router: Router, overrideUrlService: overrideUrlService) {
  router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        //have the override logic in some injectable service
        overrideUrlService.checkUrl(event.url);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a non-obstrusive and clean way would be to wrap router navigation in a helper class (or function) that implements your application-specific needs.

```
@Injectable
class LocationAwareRouter {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

    public navigate(url: string) {
        this.router.navigate(url, { skipLocationChange: this.isLocationChange(url) };
    }

    private isLocationChange(url: string): boolean {
        return /* your fancy URL evaluation here */ ;
    }
}
```